# How to save PNG clipboard contents to file on Mac

Tags: macos, shell, applescript

Because `pbpaste` doesn't work for image data, I'm using the following command to save the PNG contents of the clipboard to a file from the terminal (actually, from a `system()` command in another language, but the problem also occurs in terminals):

```
osascript -e "set png_data to the clipboard as «class PNGf»" \
  -e "set the_file to open for access POSIX path of \
      (POSIX file \"image.png\") with write permission" \
  -e "write png_data to the_file" \
  -e "close access the_file"
```

If the file already exists, this command works as desired, overwriting its contents, but if the file does not exist I get the error:

```
execution error: Network file permission error. (-5000)
```

What's the correct method of writing a new file from AppleScript? Is there a better method of saving clipboard data to a file from a terminal/system() command than this?

Comment: What is the path to /image.png?

Comment: @jweaks The command is literally as it appears in the question with the relative path `image.png`. I’m running the command from my home directory, `~`.

Comment: AppleScript doesn’t support relative paths. Always use absolute paths. Also make sure to `set eof the_file to 0` before overwriting or you may leave old data at the end of your new file.

Comment: @has Once I've gotten it working, I won't actually ever be overwriting the file, but thanks for the tip! If you can shed any light on [my comment to jweaks's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142470/how-to-save-png-clipboard-contents-to-file-on-mac#comment81243593_47144350), I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AppleScript:

```
set png_data to the clipboard as «class PNGf»
set the_file to open for access POSIX path of (POSIX file "/image.png") with write permission
write png_data to the_file
close access the_file
```

errors on line 2 even from within Script Editor, highlighting the problem is with your path designation to image.png. You never fully specify the file path. There is no assumed context of the home folder as in when working in the command line. You must specify the full path.
You need to add something like:

```
set posixPath to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
```

Comment: Using an absolute path does indeed fix it. Thanks! However, the [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28) states: "POSIX paths without a leading slash, such as "folder/file", are resolved relative to the POSIX working directory. This is supported, but only is useful for scripts run from the shell—the working directory is the current directory in the shell." Is the documentation incorrect, or am I just misreading it?

Comment: I also tried saving the commands into a script file in case that piece of documentation doesn't apply to `-e` arguments, but I still get the same error. Using an absolute path will work fine in the context I'm using it (it won't always be in the home folder, but I do know what the "current directory" is), so I'll most likely accept this answer tomorrow: leaving it open for now in case you can shed any further insight.

Comment: It does also seem to me that if the problem were down to the path it would still occur even if the file already existed: the path is the same in both cases.

Comment: I agree it's frustrating and not predictable. The same "absolute path works/relative path doesn't work" when creating a new file using open for access problem also occurs when entered directly in Terminal. Hard to say if it's a bug or a sandbox issue. If you didn't have full path in your context, you could 'touch' the file first.

Comment: "touch" was my workaround *before* I opened this question ;).

Comment: the generated file is aways 520kb, but my source image is only 8kb. I don't know why